# Android Studio Project deleted after moving to a different folder

Tags: java, android-studio

I moved a Android Studio project to a different folder, while the project was still open. Now most of the project is gone and I am left with some default files:   app.iml, TabTest.iml (which was the name of my project) and unfamiliar xml files: default.xml, encoding.xml and workspace.xml.
Can anybody help me? If you need any of the files, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project isn't gone, it's just been moved. Android Studio created a template project in the old location since it was open and it 'expected' an android project there.

Just open your moved project in Android Studio `File -> Open` and choose your project(the 'new' moved one, not the 'old' one).